Screen lock logs me out completely. 24.04
I've clean installed Ubuntu 24.04. After some time of inactivity, the screen locks (even though I've disabled this in settings, not sure why the screen locks) and when I enter my password to unlock, I lose my previously active session as if I was logged out completely.
Unlocking after screen lock results in completely logging out from my previous session and losing all of my opened applications and logging back in. This never happened in 22.04.
Screen lock setting:


I also am having lots of issues.

after a long delay (no activity),  the screen goes black and then after about 30 seconds, the login screen appears.
2, I have clearly been logout??? why, screensaver is off, etc.


Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513268/24-04-logs-out-when-unplugging-monitor-from-computer Worth mentioning from this post: try locking the session before closing the lid and removing the monitor.

Happens to me as well when I log out using the top right buttons, where I have to confirm my logout. But not if I log out using Super+L Is there a bug report on this?

Happens to me too. This drives me crazy.

I had the same issue on the HP ProBook laptop with a fresh setup of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. After re-login, all running apps were found rudely and forcibly closed. It seems this method helped me:

Edit the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file, uncomment the HandleLidSwitch=suspend line, and save changes.
Run in Terminal sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind and then reboot.

P.S. I found the solution here.

For those who decided to use this method: sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind froze my desktop (not notebook) completely. Had to use the "Power Off" button to switch it off.

I had a similar issue with clean install of ubuntu 24.04. Either if the screen locked automatically or by pressing super+L I often found that on logging in again it would present me with a clean desktop environment with nothing running. Also, the screen went blank on logging in on these ocassions (possibly also showing the bootloader logo??).
I managed to resolve it by installing vanilla gnome, on which I am not using Wayland (so using X). I'm wondering if using Wayland under the ubuntu gnome may have caused my issues (I only thought of this after changing to vanilla gnome). I was having a lot of weird display issues on ubuntu gnome, which in retrospect perhaps were caused by Wayland. I have not been brave enough to try using Wayland on vanilla.
FYI Wayland is the inevitable future apparently https://news.itsfoss.com/gnome-wayland-xorg/

The bug exists in X too.
