24.04 logs out when unplugging monitor from computer
I have multiple monitors, when unplugging or turning one off, the session logs out. Ubuntu 24.04

I am running into this same issue, I have 3 monitors connected to a KVM, and when toggling between different devices Ubuntu 24.04 kills the session and logs out. I haven't been able to find a fix yet, but this post gave me a workaround. Locking the device before unplugging the monitors seems to work.

My biggest mystery is how such a bug can slip in between 23.10 and 24.04. I am using nvidia drivers, are you?

Yeah, currently running nvidia-driver-535 on a 3080Ti. I can't figure it out either, seems like a pretty inconvenient and persistent issue for years!

I have this problem (using 24.04) and am not using Nvidia

It looks like Wayland crashes when monitor comes up (you can check it up by playing some audio and then turning monitor off and on). And I think essentially the bug is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2064037
